# Importing module without type definition in react-typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am trying to import a module named [blink-detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blink-detection) in my project. The library does not have any type definition. So, I have created a file named `types/blink-detection.d.ts` in project root. I have also changed my `tsconfig.json`

```
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types"
  ]
```

My `blink-detection.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'blink-detection';
```

But, I am getting an error message: `export 'default' (imported as 'blink') was not found in 'blink-detection' (module has no exports)`. But, the `index.js` of blink-detection has default export:

```
const blink = {
  loadModel: loadModel,
  setUpCamera: setUpCamera,
  stopPrediction: stopPrediction,
  getBlinkPrediction: renderPrediction,
};

export default blink;
```

My typescript version: 4.5.3, react version is 17.0.2 and webpack version is 5.0.66.

Comment: Reading [the TypeScript handbook section about authoring declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) will be helpful to you.

Comment: @jsejcksn Whats wrong with this code? : https://gist.github.com/desertSniper87/09d25f6fa04b4a4574657a2bf18faf71

Comment: `export =` syntax can be problematic. Did you check with `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"skipLibCheck": true` tsconfig options?

Comment: @tymzap yes. { "skipLibCheck": true,    "esModuleInterop": true }